# Populating Elasticsearch Dates From Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame in Spark with a scheme like:

```
id: string
style: string
creationdate: string
```

My dates are datetime strings like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS". I am converting "creationdate" from string to date using:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("creationdate2", $"creationdate".cast(DateType))
             .drop($"creationdate")
             .withColumnRenamed("creationdate2", "creationdate")
```

This results in:

```
id: string
style: string
creationdate: date
```

I am attempting to populate an Elasticsearch index with the date mapping defined as:

```
     "creationdate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
```

The String to DateTime conversions appears to match this format upon printing.  However, when I go to populate the index with:

```
df2.saveToEs("myindex")
```

I get an error:

```
 org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Found unrecoverable error [169.10.29.240:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse [creationdate]; Bailing out..
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[According to the guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html) the date should be able to be parsed since it has been converted to DateType.  Any ideas?  Should the schema be showing DateType instead of date?  Am I doing the conversion wrong?

Comment: What happens when you do df2.show()?  And can you saveToEs() without casting to Date?

Comment: @PaulBack Everything looks good upon show(), the date is trimmed to just yyyy-MM-dd as expected.  saveToEs() throws the same error without the cast

Comment: And you revised the index on the ES side to expect a string type?

Comment: @PaulBack One odd thing is that when I grab the a random creationdate and get its type its of java.sql.Date - the ES guide shows it must be of type   org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType

Comment: Yes it has no prob accepting them as string @PaulBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by taking one more step and converting java.sql.Date back to a string.  Using a UDF:

```
val dateToString = udf((date: java.sql.Date) => date.toString)
```